How do we define the Hilbert space for a gauge theory?
I understand that this question has duplicates. However, I'd like to ask it in a different and very particular manner.
When we talk about Hilbert space, it is not necessarily defined by normalizable states like fock space for a free lattice scalar QFT or complete set of normablizable wave functions for a one particle 1d QM system.
Instead, in one particle 1d QM system, the Hilbert space is defined by an complete eigenstate of $x$ or $p$, with $[x,p]=1$
In scalar QFT, we promote $[x,p]=1$ to infinite degrees of freedom on lattice or continuum.
In this manner, we define the Hilbert space that physics take place regardless of what kind of theory or $\cal H$ we specify, free or interacting. On the other hand, the fock space is no more than a solution to the free hamilton that acts on this hilbert space.
Now, can we define the hilbert space of gauge theory in a similar manner without any reference to free photon/gluon fock space? Using only operators, commutation relations and its eigenstates?
I know it is possible to do this by fixing a gauge. However, what I'm looking for is a gauge invariant description in this manner.

The short answer in 4d: We don't because it is to hard. Long answer: We use either geometric quantization, deformation quantization, K-theory or Dirac quantization but no one has a clue how to do that  in 4d gauge theory.

@Simp Dirac quantization is possible when you fix gauge. But the result is very ugly.

With finitely many degrees of freedom as in non relativistic QM you have the Stone von-Neumann theorem that tells you essentially that all representations of the canonical commutation relations are equivalent. This allows you in a sense to define the Hilbert space once and for all and then study interactions after. In QFT you have infinitely many degrees of freedom and the theorem doesn’t apply anymore. You have inequivalent representations of the CCR and in a sense the problem of defining the Hilbert space is not separable from studying the dynamics.

@Gold How do you know that there are inequivalent representations of the CCR?

@flippiefanus Haag's theorem.
